# Wait for element to be clickable Chrome Print Dialog

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I've had some success with Selenium for my own projects, and now I'm trying to use it to automate a printing task. I've gotten it right up to the point where it waits for the page to automatically open the print window.

```
print("finding button")
#Wait until print preview is ready
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sidebar']//print-preview-button-strip//div/cr-button[1]")))
print("button found")
time.sleep(2)
```

I've tried a few different methods to try and get this to work, as well as:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='sidebar']//print-preview-button-strip//div/cr-button[1]")))
print("button found")
time.sleep(2)
```

EDIT: I've also tried:

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 999999999);
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "action-button")))
print("button found")
time.sleep(2)
```

Just seems to hang and not proceed. I've threw a few prints to see what steps it gets stuck on, and will print right before this, and not after. Even after a couple of minutes.

Hope you can help! Selenium Python.

Comment: can you give the url to the website you're trying automate?

Comment: @AndreyKotov Unfortunately I can't, the page if a shipping dispatch list with personal information. It's just CTRL + P in Chrome. The dialog pops up automatically and I'm trying to get my script to wait for that because sometimes the dispatch list is long and takes a minute to complete loading